# Array is printing the result before calling the function in .format?

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have an insertion function that works with no issues and returns the same array but swapped around. I noticed that whenever I do the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    testing_arrays = [2, 8, 5, 3, 9, 4]

    print("Original array {} vs Sorted Array {}".format(testing_arrays, insertion_sort(testing_arrays)))
```

It results in printing two sorted arrays. I would expect it would print the unsorted one first then the sorted array after the function call but this is not the case.

I understand that I could just declare another value to the same array but I want to understand why is this happening? I would think it would not write to memory before the function call in the `print.format` function? Even if you declare a value that stores the resulted sorted array, it would be the same issue which is very interesting.

In case it was needed, here is my insertion sort function:

```
def insertion_sort(unsorted_array=None):
    for value in unsorted_array:

        #This checks whether we are at the first item or not
        #Insertion sort works by looking at the left elements
        #Since index 0 does not have any, we continue.

        if unsorted_array.index(value) == 0:
            print("We Skipped Value {} at index {} since it is the first element".format(value, unsorted_array.index(value)))
            continue

        index_counter = unsorted_array.index(value) - 1
        current_index = unsorted_array.index(value)


        while index_counter > 0:

            #We check if a value is bigger than our current index value
            if unsorted_array[index_counter] > unsorted_array[current_index]:

                #We swap the values
                temp = unsorted_array[current_index]
                unsorted_array[current_index] = unsorted_array[index_counter]
                unsorted_array[index_counter] = temp

                #We decrease the indexes looked at to keep comparing
                index_counter = index_counter - 1
                current_index = current_index - 1
                print("Index Couter is currently {}".format(index_counter))

            else:
                #We decrease the index counter here because if a right before is not bigger,
                #We can continue looking at indexes before.
                index_counter = index_counter - 1
                continue

    
        print("Progress of array is {}".format(unsorted_array))
    return unsorted_array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `insertion_sort` function is called prior to `format` call, because it's the argument of `format` function.
Current `insertion_sort` function returns the passed list and list is mutable in Python, so it's basically passing the same array to the `format` function call.
That's why we need to create a new array inside the `insertion_sort` function and returns new array sorted. Hope this helps you understand the problem correctly.

Comment: Interesting. So since it is an argument it would get called and ran before format prints thus affecting both arrays since they are the same one in memory. But is there another way to achieve the needed result without creating extra space complexity?

Comment: No, because as I already said, list is mutable object in Python, so to print both original and sorted list at the same time, we definitely need two lists.